# One line F# code is hard to understand

Tags: f#, ocaml

What is the meaning of this one line F# snippet

```
let x x = x + 2 in x 2;;
```

It is valid and just return 4.

But what is it?? is x a function? is it also a parameter? also x seems to be calling itself (x 2) but its not marked with "rec".

Can anyone explain?

Comment: why add `ocaml` tag while it is a `F# question`?

Comment: @JacksonTale I'm not entirely sure, but it could be because it's about F#'s optional OCaml-like syntax (which isn't typical for F#).

Comment: That's not exactly idiomatic F# code.  I'd strongly consider contacting whomever gave it to you to ask them to rewrite it.

Comment: @JacksonTale This is valid OCaml too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So lets try to understand what happens.

```
let x x
```

defines a function called `x` which takes an argument of `x`.

```
`let x x = x + 2`
```

means you have a function `x` which takes an argument also called `x` and returns `x+2`

The final part `in x 2` calls the function with an argument of 2.

So the function can be written as

```
let f x = x + 2
f 2
```

which obviously returns 4.

Comment: "you have a function `x` which returns `x+2`" is confusing. I'd rather say "you have a function `x` which adds `2` to the argument passed to it".

Answer (score 7):

The 'in' means that it's not using light syntax.  Basically, the `in` means that the prior binding is defined for the following expression.  Since the `in` keyword means that the binding of x is valid for the following expression, another way of writing it would be to replace `x` with the value of the binding like so:

```ml
(fun x -> x + 2) 2
```

I think it's important to be aware of the fact that all bindings work in this way, i.e. bindings are a way of writing expressions in a more understandable way.

If you look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233199.aspx), you can learn more about the more OCaml like syntax F# has available if you have `#light off` specified (`on` is the default).

Answer (score 2):

```
let x x = x + 2 in x 2;;
```

Disambiguate the variables by renaming the outer `x` to `f`:

```
let f x = x + 2 in f 2;;
```

Indent:

```
let f x =
  x + 2
f 2
```

So it defined a function that adds two and applies it to two to get four.